# Am I able to have an IP White list range for Flask, and not a list of IP's?

Tags: python, flask

I have a basic flask server I am using for Python development with a Google Chat Bot. I would like to limit the range of IP's that can access the server to any within a certain range. For the purposes of this, say 123.0.0.1 to 123.255.255.255.

I know how to easily do this for a single IP, from similar issues seen online.

from flask import abort, request

```
@app.before_request
def limit_remote_addr():
    if request.remote_addr != '123.0.0.1':
        abort(403)  # Forbidden
```

But I don't want to do this for every IP, or have to make a list. Is that possible? Or am I better off configuring my firewall to remove this step?

Comment: `if not request.remote_addr.startswith('123.'):`

Answer (score 1):

As @Klaus D. mentioned you can check if the remote address starts with a portion of the address.

You can check if the remote address is listed in a specific list of IP addresses in `@before_request` decorator.

Here I am showing an example of white listing IP addresses in Python.

Used local network(connected via WiFi) to test it.

Local IP address for Flask server: `192.168.0.107`

`app.py`:

```
from flask import abort, Flask, render_template, request


ALLOWED_IPS = ['192.168.1.', '127.0.0.1']

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(403)
def permission_error(e):
    return render_template('403.html', error_code=403), 403

@app.before_request
def limit_remote_addr():
    client_ip = str(request.remote_addr)
    valid = False
    for ip in ALLOWED_IPS:
        if client_ip.startswith(ip) or client_ip == ip:
            valid = True
            break
    if not valid:
        abort(403)


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    return "Your IP: {}".format(request.remote_addr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

`403.html`:

```
<h3>Your IP address is not white listed</h3>
```

**Output:**

Accessing the app from a IP which is not in `ALLOWED_IPS` list:

[image: blocked IP]

Accessing the app from a IP which is in `ALLOWED_IPS` list:

[image: white listed IP]

After updating the `ALLOWED_IPS` list to `ALLOWED_IPS = ['192.168.0.', '127.0.0.1']`, I can access the Flask app from `192.168.0.107`:

[image: valid IP]